# Error in Word document generated in document library through workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library, word

I have created a list in SharePoint with a corresponding document library. When a user has created an item in the list they can choose to generate a word document that lists the data from their form. I have had a working version before where, depending on which button was used, a different document would be generated in a separate document library (2 versions).

I now have had to update this so the 2 documents are merged so only a single button is required. I have made the necessary updates to both my form and workflow and created a new document library that uses the new Word template.

Now when I create a document with this form I sometimes get the error "We're sorry. We can't open [document title].docx because we found a problem with its contents." If I check the details of this error the only information I get is that there is an "unspecified error". (error message in screen below)

[image]

The weirdest thing, to me, is that this error doesn't always appear. For now I have been using three records to test and so far it only occurs on the first document creation of the first of those records. So if I create a new document for that record that has an existing document (with the error) in the library the system adds a datetime stamp to the filename and this version I can open. If I then delete the original document and create it again (no datetime stamp added since the original title no longer exists) the error still persists. After this I had created a new record that contains the exact same data (except for two date fields due to form validation) and this record does not contain the error.

Does anyone know what might cause this error to appear and how I would be able to solve this?

If you need any more information, please let me know and I will add it accordingly.

Thanks in advance!